# NSTableViewDelegate with 2 tables and tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification

Tags: cocoa

I have 2 tables whose delegate is the same object. Struggling with the syntax on how to accommodate this.  I have the other delegate methods working correctly as they are passing the NSTableView object.

An example most appreciated

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Alight figured it out.  Pretty simple actually.

```
[[aNotification object] identifier]
```

contains the table name.