# How to learn in Swift inside 'tableViewSelectionDidChange:' in which NSTableView the selection did change?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview

I have a macOS project where there are two tableView with the same viewControl as delegate. How can I learn which of the two is called on tableViewSelectionDidChange:?

EDIT: I'm using `tableViewSelectionDidChange:` to prevent some items I use as a sort of "title group" from being clicked.

I read this question [NSTableViewDelegate with 2 tables and tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529725/nstableviewdelegate-with-2-tables-and-tableviewselectiondidchangensnotificatio/9548141#comment77194098_9548141) but being a beginner, I don't know how to do this in Swift.

I tried

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

    let tableViewName = (notification.object? as AnyObject).identifier // error

    if tableViewName == myTableView1 {
        print("myTableView1")
    }

}
```

but I get the "Ambiguous use of Identifier" error. Is somebody so kind to tell me what I'm doing wrong? A working example would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of [NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewselectiondidchangenotification?language=objc)

> **The notification object is the table view whose selection changed**. This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.

So the object is clearly non-optional and a table view instance. It's **not** `AnyObject`

```
let tableView = notification.object as! NSTableView

if let identifier = tableView.identifier, identifier == "myTableView1" {
    print("myTableView1")
}
```

Comment: Thank you vadian! Works fine

Comment: @vadian Why would an NSTableView not have an identifier? I’m using identifiers to tell which NSTableView gets passed to my delegate methods and have met no problem so far.

Comment: @Pal  `NSTableView` doesn't have an `identifier` property, probably you mean the identifiers for cell views and columns.

Comment: I don’t get it. I just tried the following in a playground, it works:
`import Cocoa
 /*\n*/ 
let tv = NSTableView()
 /*\n*/ 
tv.identifier = "Here."
 /*\n*/ 
print(tv.identifier!)`

Comment: My apologies, you are right, I overlooked the `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification` protocol. Answer edited.